# How to detect collision?

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, dom

I am building a video game where a spaceship moves with controllers and it must avoid some fireballs in order to win. However now I would like to setup a collision system: when a fireball touches the spaceship, game is over (alert("game over")). Any help with this? Thanks!!!

```
let spaceship = document.querySelector("#icon")

//Fireball script
const fireballArray = []

function generateFireBallWithAttributes(el, attrs) {
    for (var key in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key])
    };
    return el
}

function createFireBalls(amount) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
        fireballArray.push(generateFireBallWithAttributes(document.createElement("img"), {
            src: "Photo/fireball.png",
            width: "40"
        }))
    }
}
createFireBalls(10)
fireballArray.forEach((fireballElement) => {
    const fallStartInterval = setInterval(function() {})
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(fireballElement);
    const fireballMovement = {
        x: fireballRandom(fireballElement.offsetWidth),
        y: 0
    }
    const fireLoop = function() {
        fireballMovement.y += 2;
        fireballElement.style.top = fireballMovement.y + "px";
        if (fireballMovement.y > window.innerHeight) {
            fireballMovement.x = fireballRandom(fireballElement.offsetWidth);
            fireballElement.style.left = fireballMovement.x + "px";
            fireballMovement.y = 0
        }
    }
    fireballElement.style.left = fireballMovement.x + "px";
    let fireInterval = setInterval(fireLoop, 1000 / ((Math.random() * (50)) + 75))
})

function fireballRandom(offset) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - offset))
}

//Spaceship moves into space + prevent going out borders
let hits = 0
let pos = {
    top: 1000,
    left: 570
}
const keys = {}
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true
})
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false
})
const loop = function() {
    if (keys[37] || keys[81]) {pos.left -= 5}
    if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {pos.left += 5}
    if (keys[38] || keys[90]) {pos.top -= 4}
    if (keys[40] || keys[83]) {pos.top += 4}
    if (pos.left < 0) { pos.left = -1}
    if (pos.top < 0) {pos.top = -1}
    if (pos.left + spaceship.offsetWidth >= body.offsetWidth) {
        pos.left = body.offsetWidth - spaceship.offsetWidth
    }
    if (pos.top + spaceship.offsetHeight >= body.offsetHeight) {
        pos.top = body.offsetHeight - spaceship.offsetHeight
    }
    spaceship.setAttribute("data", body.offsetWidth + ":" + body.offsetHeight)
    spaceship.style.left = pos.left + "px";
    spaceship.style.top = pos.top + "px"
}
let sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 8)

<body>
<img src="Photo/Spaceship1.png" id="icon">
</body>
```

[Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection) (hitboxes)
[Also this](https://jsfiddle.net/jlr7245/217jrozd/3/)

Comment: OT: Why are you not using a framework like babylon or similar ?

Comment: Uhm, thanks but I think I'll stick to this... game is nearly over (when question is answered, game is officially over)

Comment: @Thomas can you make a codesandbox or something like that first. also, add a @ when you want to mention someone next time

Comment: @Thomas in the text editor (click edit under the question) search for `javascript/html/css snippet` next to image icon

Comment: host the images in imgur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing complete information. That said, as your game progresses with explicit and independent setIntervals on fireballs and spaceship, and you dont want to make bigger changes I suggest you call the `checkCollision()` function any time fireball moves or spaceship moves (that is in the `loop` and `fireloop` "animation functions").

The collision itself is done with the following:

```js
function detectOverlap(fireball) {
  const shipRect = spaceship.getBoundingClientRect();
  const fireballRect = fireball.getBoundingClientRect();
  //these two variables are of following type 
  //DOMRect {x: 570, y: 836, width: 104.484375, height: 112.828125, ...}

  // this will test if the ship collides with specific fireball
  if (
    (shipRect.x + shipRect.width > fireballRect.x && shipRect.x < fireballRect.x + fireball.width)
    && (shipRect.y + shipRect.height > fireballRect.y && shipRect.y < fireballRect.y + fireball.height)
  ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

function checkCollision() {
  let collision = false;
  fireballArray.forEach(fireball => {
    if (detectOverlap(fireball)) { collision = true };
  });

  // this is satisfied if the ship collides with any fireball
  if (collision === true) {
    // do some logic on collision
    console.log('collision');
  }
};
```

This will do rectangle vs rectangle collision detection. This might not fit the best, but it is a good first approximation.

NOTE: You can check the devtools console (F12) to assess the correct collision detection.